# Calculate correlation of any pair of stocks

Tags: r, correlation

I want to get the correlation between monthly returns for each pair of stocks...

Let me show you a simple version of my data:

```
> head(x, 20)
# A tibble: 20 x 4
   PERMNO     date         COMNAM       RET
    <int>    <int>          <chr>     <dbl>
 1  10107 20160129 MICROSOFT CORP -0.007030
 2  10107 20160229 MICROSOFT CORP -0.069886
 3  10107 20160331 MICROSOFT CORP  0.085495
 4  10107 20160429 MICROSOFT CORP -0.097049
 5  10107 20160531 MICROSOFT CORP  0.069982
 6  10107 20160630 MICROSOFT CORP -0.034528
 7  10107 20160729 MICROSOFT CORP  0.107680
 8  10107 20160831 MICROSOFT CORP  0.020113
 9  10107 20160930 MICROSOFT CORP  0.002436
10  10107 20161031 MICROSOFT CORP  0.040278
11  10107 20161130 MICROSOFT CORP  0.012183
12  10107 20161230 MICROSOFT CORP  0.031198
13  14593 20160129      APPLE INC -0.075242
14  14593 20160229      APPLE INC -0.001335
15  14593 20160331      APPLE INC  0.127211
16  14593 20160429      APPLE INC -0.139921
17  14593 20160531      APPLE INC  0.071368
18  14593 20160630      APPLE INC -0.042660
19  14593 20160729      APPLE INC  0.090063
20  14593 20160831      APPLE INC  0.023606
```

Ideally, I would like a correlation measure for pairs of stocks in my data (Microsoft and Apple, Microsoft and Costco, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your data into a dataframe of returns whose column titles are company names, and you should just be able to pass it into the `cor` function.  If your dataframe is called `df`, for example, you might use the `dplyr` and `tidyr` libraries:

```
df1 = dplyr::select(df, date, COMNAM, RET)
df2 = dplyr::select(tidyr::spread(df1, key = COMNAM, value = RET), -date)
answer = cor(df2, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

I cleaned your data so `COMNAM` was only the first word of the multi-word company name.  This is the output I get:

```
> answer
              APPLE MICROSOFT
APPLE     1.0000000 0.8763755
MICROSOFT 0.8763755 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more complete example and might open some doors to new ideas for performing this type of analysis and/or where/how to obtain the data:

```
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

symbols <- c("AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG")
getSymbols(symbols)
stocks <- data.frame(as.xts(merge(AAPL, MSFT, GOOG)))
stocks$date <- row.names(stocks)
row.names(stocks) <- NULL

# head(stocks)

jan31 <- ymd("2016-01-31")
days_to_keep <- jan31 %m+% months(0:11)
# days_to_keep

res <- stocks %>%
  select(ends_with("Close"), date) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  filter(date %in% days_to_keep)

res %>% select(-date) %>% cor()

#            AAPL.Close MSFT.Close GOOG.Close
# AAPL.Close  1.0000000  0.9198357  0.9313001
# MSFT.Close  0.9198357  1.0000000  0.9103830
# GOOG.Close  0.9313001  0.9103830  1.0000000

# Or more visually...
res %>% select(-date) %>% pairs()
```

Comment: Nice one Jason!!